# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

and this is my code:

```
class Table extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: [],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getEmployeeList();
    }
    getEmployeeList = () => {
        axios.get("employee/list")
        .then(function(response) {

            this.setState({
                employees: response.data,
            });

        });
        console.log(this.state.employees)
    }
     
    // Remaining codes
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the callback you pass in is a *function expression*, which has its own `this` binding.

To solve this error you can:

1. Use *arrow functions*:

```
getEmployeeList = () => {
  axios
    .get("employee/list")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        employees: response.data,
      });
    });
};
```

2. Save `this` to `self` variable, and call it instead:

```
getEmployeeList = () => {
  const self = this;
  axios
    .get("employee/list")
    .then(function (response) {
      self.setState({
        employees: response.data,
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are passing an anonymous function to the `axios.then` callback.

```
axios.get("employee/list")
.then(function(response) {

    this.setState({
        employees: response.data,
    });

});
```

This function has it's own `this` that has no `setState` property on it. To solve this issue, you have to either bind `this` like so:

```
axios.then(
  function (response) {
    this.setState({
      employees: response.data
    });
  }.bind(this)
);
```

Or use an arrow function, which will bind the outer `this` automatically

```
axios.then(
 (response) =>{

    this.setState({
      employees: response.data
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

kindly recheck your spelling. Most typeError issues are due to spelling mistakes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).